# Cannot make xdg-mime query return chosen browser

Tags: linux-mint, mime-types, xdg

After maybe one year of using Chromium as the default browser, my Linux switched spontaneously to using Firefox (probably because of some updates). I want to switch back. Based on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/467920/10802), I executed

```
xdg-mime default google-chrome.desktop text/html
```

and verified the result using

```
xdg-mime query default text/html
```

but it keeps returning `firefox.desktop`.

I tried several times, and got no errors and my `~/.config/mimeapps.list` gets touched when I execute the first command above. However, the response remains `firefox.desktop` and when clicking on a link on the command line, Firefox opens. Note that there's no single occurrence of `firefox.desktop` in my `mimeapps.list`.

There's obviously something overriding my settings... Any idea what?

---

```
Linux jmpx19 4.15.0-88-generic #88-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 11 20:11:34 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Distributor ID: LinuxMint
Description:    Linux Mint 19 Tara
Release:    19
Codename:   tara
```

#### Update

As suggested in the comment, I tried

```
XDG_UTILS_DEBUG_LEVEL=4 xdg-mime query default text/html
```

and got

```
Checking /home/maaartinus/.config/mimeapps.list
Checking /home/maaartinus/.local/share/applications/xfce-defaults.list and /home/maaartinus/.local/share/applications/xfce-mimeinfo.cache
Checking /home/maaartinus/.local/share/applications/defaults.list and /home/maaartinus/.local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache
Checking /usr/share/xfce4/applications/xfce-defaults.list and /usr/share/xfce4/applications/xfce-mimeinfo.cache
Checking /usr/share/xfce4/applications/defaults.list and /usr/share/xfce4/applications/mimeinfo.cache
Checking /home/maaartinus/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share/applications/xfce-defaults.list and /home/maaartinus/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share/applications/xfce-mimeinfo.cache
Checking /home/maaartinus/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share/applications/defaults.list and /home/maaartinus/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache
Checking /var/lib/flatpak/exports/share/applications/xfce-defaults.list and /var/lib/flatpak/exports/share/applications/xfce-mimeinfo.cache
Checking /var/lib/flatpak/exports/share/applications/defaults.list and /var/lib/flatpak/exports/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache
Checking /usr/local/share/applications/xfce-defaults.list and /usr/local/share/applications/xfce-mimeinfo.cache
Checking /usr/local/share/applications/defaults.list and /usr/local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache
Checking /usr/share/applications/xfce-defaults.list and /usr/share/applications/xfce-mimeinfo.cache
Checking /usr/share/applications/defaults.list and /usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache
firefox.desktop
```

My `/home/maaartinus/.config/mimeapps.list` looks like

```
[Added Associations]
text/csv=libreoffice-calc.desktop;
...
text/x-csrc=xed.desktop;

[Default Applications]
text/html=google-chrome.desktop
...
```

Comment: `XDG_UTILS_DEBUG_LEVEL=4 xdg-mime query default text/html` might tell you where it's looking.

Comment: @JoshBrobst It looks like `xdg-mime` doesn't recognize the entry it wrote in my `mimeapps.list` and continues to system `defaults.list`.

Comment: Ah I just noticed you said you're trying to switch back to chromium, try setting it to `chromium.desktop`.

Comment: @JoshBrobst This didn't help either, the result is exactly the same. :(

Comment: Ok I tried out Mint and it seems to be `chromium-browser.desktop`.

Comment: @JoshBrobst I tried `chromium-browser.desktop` after your second comment - no success. Now I tried *all four lines* from the linked answer where I substituted it for `google-chrome.desktop` and now it works.... no idea what's going on, but it's solved for me. Many thanks.